# AnimationUtils not animating 1 of my custom views

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a customview called CardSlot that is part of a layout that I use twice in a layout, roughly:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <PlayerLayout 4 CardSlots defined... />   #Layout1
    <LinearLayout 2 CardSlots defined/>
    <PlayerLayout 4 CardSlots defined.../>       #layout2
</LinearLayout>
```

The WarSlot card is initially invisible. I call the animation like this :

GameFragment:

```
public void onEvent(GameMsg msg) {
    switch (msg) {
        case XXX:
            for (int idx = playerLayouts.length-1; idx >= 0; idx--) {
                playerLayouts[idx].animateWarCard(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_in));
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

PlayerLayout:

```
public void animateWarCard(Animation animation) {//TODO why no show for layout2???
    Log.v(TAG, "animate?  " + mdata.player.getClass().getSimpleName());
    cardSlots[WARSLOT].setAnimation(animation);
    animation.setStartTime(3500);
    animation.setDuration(3500);
    animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            Log.v(TAG, "onAnimationStart " + animation);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            Log.v(TAG, "onAnimationEnd " + animation);
            cardSlots[WARSLOT].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
    });
    animation.startNow();
    Log.v(TAG, "started?");
}
```

Now, the animation for layout1 works fine, but it won't start for layout2 (none of the listener's log messages show).  Even if I just call layout2 directly and leave out layout1 it does not work.  There are no errors or exceptions that I can see in the log, even unfiltered.

Any ideas on what I should look for or different way to make the calls?

Comment: check if you are meeting the for loop condition for custom layout

Comment: There are 2 slots so idx starts as 1 and since the condition is idx >= 0 it will go through both.  Also this is a different revision where I was initially going from for (int idx=0; idx<array.length; idx++)